# Completing CompletableFuture<T> before adding a callback

Tags: java, java-8

Is there any chance that by the moment `thenApply`/`thenAccept` methods are called for new CompletableFuture object, the future's execution will have already been finished and setting handlers via aforementioned methods won't have any effect? 
I am not just having these two methods in mind, but the whole bunch of ~50 methods that accept handlers of the CompletableFuture API.

```
CompletableFuture<String> f = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> toString());

f.thenApply(s -> f); // will be called if "f" completes before this line is invoked?
```

Comment: Put a `Thread.sleep` between the two and log the thread in the callback to `thenApply`.

Comment: What do you mean with “won’t have any effect”? Of course, they still have an effect, just immediately, instead of later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

If a promise has already resolved, any callbacks you add in the future will execute immediately.